# Estimate with a probability of $68\%$, for how many humans the medicine has a positive effect

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> For a rare illness, there is a new medicine on the market which has a
>   positive effect of $45\%$ on all use cases. $50$ patients take this
>   medicine.
>
> **Estimate** with a probability of $68\%$, for how many humans this
>   medicine has a positive effect.

I'm very confused by the word 'Estimate'... So the entire model of this problem seems to be the binomial distribution. Formula:

$$P(X=k)=\binom{n}{k} \cdot p^k \cdot (1-p)^{n-k}$$

And we are looking for $n$ because the question is 'for how many humans'. The given $68\%$ should be put it for $P(X=k)$ and our $p$ is $45\%$.

But then we are missing both $k$ and $n$ so there is no way to calculate $n$...?

I don't see how this could work, maybe somehow by making use of the expected value?

So $E(X) = n\cdot p$ but then our $n$ is unknown and the expected value itself is unknown too : /

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, you have $n$ as the total number of patients, which is $50$, and you are asked to calculate the maximum $k$ such that $P(X \leq k) < 68\%$ where $p = 0.45$.